# Serve infinite data as a stream in Java Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, streaming

I'm trying to write a servlet which can publish infinite live data to connected clients. Probably that would be in a `while(true)` loop, and whenever the servlet writes to `response.getOutputStream()` I want to receive it from connected client. But in almost all examples around internet (like file download) client begins to receive (via input stream) right after server finish writing. Is there a possible read/write method to do this operation synchronized in servlets? Or do I have to use sockets?

Notice that I will be a Spring REST service and that's why I'm keen on servlets, instead of any technology.

Thanks all!

Comment: It is hard to make sure what is being asked here. Could you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve, what do you mean by "publish infinite live data to connected clients"?  At least give us some examples. From this vouge question I can only conclude, that it is not the Spring REST framework that fits for what you might want to achieve,  but rather the Netty framework, please consult this user guide http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-5.x.html

Comment: Thanks for comment. Just imagine this servlet will push data forever (like feeding up from a queue, for instance). Live data example is just a realization. I'll check for netty.

Comment: This is called *asynchronous servlets* not *synchronized*.